# Pyserial: weird permission denied

Tags: python, permission-denied, pyserial, tty

I use [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) to open a serial port in my program. This works fine if I have inserted the USB device prior to starting the program. If however I insert the USB device using execution I get a `permission denied` error.

**My code**

```
import serial, sys

def get_serial_port():
    ser_devs = [dev for dev in os.listdir('/dev') if dev.startswith('ttyAC')]
    if len(ser_devs) > 0:
        return '/dev/'+ser_devs[0]
    return None

while(1):
    port = get_serial_port()
    if port:
        print('Will open port %s' % port)
        ser = serial.Serial(port)
```

**Error**:

Inserting the USB device while the program is running gives me the below error

```
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyACM0:
                       [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyACM0'
```

This doesn't make sense to me since it otherwise works. I am in `dialgroup` and I run python as normal user.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Maybe try rate-limiting the `while(1):` loop?

Comment: @BlueIce Changing it has unfortunately no effect..

Comment: Is the device you're connecting to an Arduino? If so, which board and tell us if you're also having the Arduino Software IDE open.

Comment: @OliverW. almost. It's an [Mbed microcontroller](http://developer.mbed.org/platforms/mbed-LPC1768). I tried with different boards however and the same thing happens.

Comment: I assume `dialgroup` is a typo and you are in group `dialout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuously trying to open the port finally succeeds after a while actually. So hiding the errors makes it work for the moment:

```
while(1):
    port = get_serial_port()
    if port:
        print('Will open port %s' % port)
        try:
            ser = serial.Serial(port, 9600)
            print(ser.readline())
        except:
            pass
```

This ofcourse is just a hack. The behaviour is still very weird and I am not sure if it's pyserial that is buggy or some other program is interfering with the serial.

I noticed that as fast as I plug the USB device, modem-manager starts using the serial port for a few seconds:

```
ModemMana  851        root 8u  CHR  166,0  0t0  16925693 /dev/ttyACM0
gmain      851   879  root 8u  CHR  166,0  0t0  16925693 /dev/ttyACM0
gdbus      851   884  root 8u  CHR  166,0  0t0  16925693 /dev/ttyACM0
```

I still don't see how this 'bug' could give a `Permission denied` error though. I would expect in this case a `Device busy` exception.

Comment: ERR 13 not **Port bussy exception !**  System closed or deactivated related bus. Ask your system **"What am I supposed to do? On creating an infinite loop on hardware."**  Python applications cannot create an infinite loop (hardware). The shell does it for you(Not Python shell, shell mean **Bash**). And this not an answer !